# Combinar consultas SQL com colunas diferentes

Tags: sql-server

Possuo as seguintes consultas, q1:

```
SELECT finempe.codigo_orgao
    ,finempe.cod_reduzido
    ,finempe.num_empenho
    ,finempe.data_empenho
    ,finempe.nome_fornecedor
    ,finempe.valor_empenhado 
    ,finempe.valor_anulado
    ,finempe.valor_pago
    ,finempe.valor_liquidado
    ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_liquidado as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_liquidar
    ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_pago as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_pagar
  FROM [Cont98].[dbo].[finempe]
  where finempe.codigo_orgao = 01   and finempe.data_empenho between '01-01-1998' and  '31-12-1998'  
  order by finempe.cod_reduzido, finempe.num_empenho
```

e, q2:

```
SELECT cod_reduzido
      ,sld_orc_ano
      ,sld_supl_ano
      ,sld_esp_ano
      ,sld_ext_ano
      ,sld_re_ano
      ,orcplade.descricao
  FROM Cont98.dbo.orcdotac
  inner join orcplade on
  (orcdotac.conta_desp = orcplade.conta_desp)
  WHERE codigo_orgao = 01  and cod_reduzido != 0
  ORDER BY cod_reduzido
```

Gostaria de combiná-las da seguinte forma: a cada `cod_reduzido` de **q2** terá *n* tuplas de **q1** (que possuem o mesmo `cod_reduzido`), como poderia resolver esse meu problema?

Comment: Você precisa que a tabela de q1 (`finempe`) se relacione com alguma das tabelas de q2 (`orcdotac` ou `orcplade`). Existe algum campo que faça isso? Tipo `finempe.id_orcdotac`

Comment: @rLinhares cara, não existe nenhum campo que faz isso, no máximo o cod_reduzido é igual para os dois, mas essas duas tabelas pertencem ao mesmo BD

Comment: É por esse `cod_reduzido` que você sabe que uma ocorrência da q1 se relaciona com x ocorrências da q2? Se sim, esse cara que vai ser usado. (se sim, em qual das duas tabelas da q2 ele está?)

Comment: Quanto ao que você falou de "essas duas tabelas pertencem ao mesmo BD", não significa que elas têm relação; por exemplo posso ter a tabela `usuarios` e a `cores_produto` que não se relacionam em nada. Entende?!

Comment: ele está nas duas tabelas, tanto em q1 quanto em q2, irei exibir em uma table html, onde o q2 seria como se fosse um título e o q1 as tuplas com as informações, mas tem N títulos e N informações.

Comment: @rLinhares , entendo... então, basicamente eles não tem relação, mas ao mesmo tempo tem, tipo um paradoxo mesmo

Answer (score 0):

**resposta atualizada**

Acredito que a ideia seja transformar as duas em uma só, já que você precisa de dados das duas. Tenta essa consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT finempe.codigo_orgao
    ,finempe.cod_reduzido
    ,finempe.num_empenho
    ,finempe.data_empenho
    ,finempe.nome_fornecedor
    ,finempe.valor_empenhado 
    ,finempe.valor_anulado
    ,finempe.valor_pago
    ,finempe.valor_liquidado
    ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_liquidado as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_liquidar
    ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_pago as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_pagar
    /*,cod_reduzido (não precisa pois será igual ao primeiro campo)*/
    ,sld_orc_ano
    ,sld_supl_ano
    ,sld_esp_ano
    ,sld_ext_ano
    ,sld_re_ano
    ,orcplade.descricao
FROM Cont98.dbo.orcdotac
INNER JOIN orcplade on (orcdotac.conta_desp = orcplade.conta_desp)
LEFT JOIN Cont98.dbo.finempe on (finempe.cod_reduzido = orcdotac.cod_reduzido)
WHERE finempe.codigo_orgao = 01
  AND finempe.data_empenho BETWEEN '01-01-1998' AND '31-12-1998'
  AND orcdotac.cod_reduzido != 0
ORDER BY cod_reduzido, finempe.num_empenho
```

Detalhe: estou admitindo que o campo cod_reduzido existe tanto na tabela `finempe` quanto na `orcdotac`. Caso não exista na segunda, podemos reformular os *joins*.

Comment: é o seguinte, gostaria que a consulta retornasse tbm os "títulos" de q2, essa consulta me retornou o mesmo resultado de q1 só que com as colunas a mais, gostaria de algo do tipo: q2 (cod_reduzido = 1) - (todas as tuplas de q1 que cod_reduzido = 1) q1, q1, q1- q2 (cod_reduzido = 2) -*aqui não possui tuplas de q1 que o cod_reduzido = 2*- q2 (cod_reduzido = 3)- q1... deu pra entender?

Comment: acho que não :D se em q2 você sabe quem deve ser mostrado em q1 através do campo `cod_reduzido`, então ele deve ser o campo de união entre as tabelas. Sendo assim, se o `cod_reduzido` é único na tabela `orcdotac`, sempre vai ser um pra um.. confere?!

Comment: na q2 terá uma (1) tupla com cada cod_reduzido, mas na q1 terá *n* tuplas com o mesmo cod_reduzido, onde: *n >= 0*

Comment: Entendi, mas então qual o erro? Pelo que entendi está retornando os mesmos dados da q1 com os campos da q2, que é o esperado

Comment: quando q1 não possui nenhuma tupla, nada é exibido, sendo que, era pra exibir os dados de q2

Comment: no caso você precisa dos dados de q2 independentemente? pode acontecer de existir um cara em q1 e não ter o correspondente em q2?

Comment: isso, sempre aparece o q2 e caso haja em q1 tuplas que possuem o mesmo cod_reduzido, elas deverão aparecer logo embaixo do q2

Comment: vou editar a resposta e você testa